# Linker error in VS2010 (2 project in solution and static method)

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, static-methods

I have a problem with error LNK2019 and LNK1120.

I have solution with two projects. In the first program I have my program, in the second project I have test files.

In the second project I can include header file (with class). And I can use inline methods. But... I have defined in header file static private method with implementation in .cpp file.
If I want to test public inline method which use this static private method I have LNK2019 error and fatal error LNK1120.

I don't know what to do... It looks good for me because I can use it in the first project without any errors...

Have a look at example...
SOLUTION:

Project1:

```
// example.h
class Example {
public:
    void method() { static_method(); };
private:
    static void static_method();
};

// example.cpp
void Example::static_method() { /* implementation */ }

// main.cpp
void main()
{
    Example e;
    e.method();    // it works!
}
```

BUT...

PROJECT2 (in SOLUTION):

```
// test.cpp
void main()
{
    Example e;
    e.method(); // it doesn't work (but if I add implementation of
                // Example::static_method() to header file example.h - it's OK)
}
```

Could You help me? [VS2010]

Thanks.

Comment: **************
I've noticed that the problem isn't connected with static method. When I use 'static' world from definitions of this method - the error still occurs. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully proj1 is a static library and proj2 is exe or dll. In that case you must add reference of proj1 to proj2, and it will work fine. (Common properties at very top/Framework and references; add new reference).

If both projects are exe, then you have to split off a library with implementation of example, leaving the rest, then refer the lib in both projects.

You can  make it a DLL too instead of static lib, but then you must use the proper exporting stuff, and make sure to produce the files in a single directory for execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the static method in the .h file like:

```
// example.h
class Example {
public:
    void method1() { static_method(); };
private:
    static void static_method() { // implementation }
};

// example.cpp
/* nothing here yet... */

// main.cpp
void main()
{
    Example e;
    e.method1();    // it works!
}
```

Comment: Thank You for you answer, I've tried it. I wrote about it in comments in my first post. It works.... But I prefer implementation in .cpp file because implementation is long. It doesn't look good for me. :( Is there any idea how to do it in cpp file?